# Store (almost) all objects in workspace in a list

Tags: r, list, global, workspace

Let's say that I have many objects in my workspace (global environment) and I want to store most of those in a list. Here's a simplified example:

```
# Put some objects in the workspace
A <- 1
B <- 2
C <- 3
```

I would like to store objects A and C in a list. Of course, I can do that explicitly:

```
mylist <- list(A,C)
```

However, when the number of objects in the workspace is very large, this would become rather cumbersome. Hence, I would like to do this differently and attempted the following:

```
mylist <- list(setdiff(ls(),B))
```

But this obviously is not what I want, as it only stores the names of the objects in the workspace.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Another option is to use `mget`:

```
mget(setdiff(ls(),"B"))
```

Comment: Didn't know about `mget`. It's much simpler !

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT :** I think using `lapply` / `sapply` here raises too many problems. You should definitely use the `mget` answer.

You can try :

```
mylist <- sapply(setdiff(ls(),"B"), get)
```

In certain cases, ie if all the objects in your workspace are of the same type, `sapply` will return a vector. For example :

```
sapply(setdiff(ls(),"B"), get)
# A C 
# 1 3
```

Otherwise, it will return a list :

```
v <- list(1:2)
sapply(setdiff(ls(),"B"), get)
# $A
# [1] 1
# 
# $C
# [1] 3
# 
# $v
# [1] 1 2
```

So using `lapply` instead of `sapply` here could be safer, as Josh O'Brien pointed out.

Comment: Should use `lapply()` to avoid (potential) conversion of list to a vector.

Comment: I think you mean `"B"` and  `mget` would be useful here., i.e. `mget( setdiff( ls() , "B" ) )` +1

Comment: @SimonO101 Yes, of course it was `"B"` and not `B`. I just copy/pasted the code in the question, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @SimonO101 Just for my understanding, why does it return a list when you enter `"B"` and a numeric vector when entering `B`?

Comment: @Rob because you are using `sapply`. Also `setdiff` will return everything (object `B` is not excluded because you are comparing the character values of the names of objects against the value held in `B` which is `2`). So it returns 3 objects in a list, all of the same length and same type so its automagically converted to a numeric vector.

Comment: @Rob Try this to see what I mean... `B <- "A"; setdiff(ls(),B)` Now object `A` gets excluded.

Answer (score 2):

`mget` is definitely the easiest to use in this situation. However, you can achieve the same with `as.list.environment` and `eapply`:

```
e2l <- as.list(.GlobalEnv)
# or: e2l <- as.list(environment()) 
# using environment() within a function returns the function's env rather than .GlobalEnv
e2l[! names(e2l) %in "B"]

# the following one sounds particularly manly with `force`
e2l <- eapply(environment(), force)
e2l[! names(e2l) %in "B"]
```

And one-liners:

```
 (function(x) x[!names(x)%in%"B"])(eapply(environment(), force))
 (function(x) x[!names(x)%in%"B"])(as.list(environment()))
```