# Place many similarly named dataframes into a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a number of datasets, all named `df_some number`. I'd like to run the same commands on all of these and save the results. Most of what I've seen suggests I should place all the datasets in a list.

How do I do this (ie, capture all of the similarly named datasets and place them in a list) without having to type the name of every dataset?

Comment: Probably `mget` is what you want.

Comment: can someone find the dupe for this?

Comment: @BenBolker Here's one possibility: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18897473/324364

Comment: Are these data sets being created by code in R, or are you reading a bunch of separate data files into separate data frames? Either way, if you put them in a list to begin with, you won't have a combine them into a list after the fact. For example, if you're loading the data from csv files, you could do `df.list = lapply(list.files(pattern="csv"), read.csv)`.

Comment: It's one large file with an identifier column I'd like to split them by. I ended up doing something like: `my.list2 <- lapply(paste('df_', brands_to_loop, sep=""), get)` 

Now I just need to understand `get`....